# SQL NOT Between dates (including NULL)

Tags: sql, t-sql, between

I'm having the following issue. I have a list of checks the system runs each hour/day. It knows which checks to run because they are in the database. Now I made a different table where I can set maintenance windows for each application. And I'm running in the following problem.

I join the maintenance window table on application id. like this:

```
Select check.appid, check.query, maint.appid 
from checks as check 
left join maintenance as maint on maint.appid = check.appid
```

After that I wanted to add a where clause I ended up with the following

```
Select check.appid, check.query, maint.appid 
from checks as check 
left join maintenance as maint on maint.appid = check.appid

WHERE
SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()
            BETWEEN 
            CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET,maint.StartDateTime AT TIME ZONE maint.[TimeZone]) 
            AND 
            CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET,maint.EndDateTime AT TIME ZONE maint.[TimeZone]);
```

This returns a list with the applications that are currently on maintenance, so is should not runs the checks.

I tried making it a NON BETWEEN. But that makes me end up with no records at all, because when there is no maintenance the start and enddate will return a null on the join.

a dirty fix could be to force a date in 1990 or something when the date is null, but there should be a cleaner option available right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to move the conditions to the `ON` clause:

```
select c.appid, c.query, m.appid 
from checks c left join
     maintenance m
     on m.appid = c.appid and
        SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() not between 
            CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET, maint.StartDateTime AT TIME ZONE maint.[TimeZone]) AND
            CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET,maint.EndDateTime AT TIME ZONE maint.[TimeZone]);
```

This returns all rows in `checks` along with the corresponding *active* information from `maintenance`.

Comment: This works! When i change between to notbetween i get the expected result! Thankyou. I just had the stuff at the wrong part of the query it seems.

Answer (score 0):

As the query stands the results will be all rows from the checks table and only those rows from the maintenance table that match by appid.

If all you want is those checks that are on maintenance you simply need to change the join to an inner join.  Or am I misunderstanding?

```sql
Select check.appid, check.query, maint.appid 
from checks as check 
**inner** join maintenance as maint on maint.appid = check.appid

WHERE
SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()
            BETWEEN 
            CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET,maint.StartDateTime AT TIME ZONE maint.[TimeZone]) 
            AND 
            CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET,maint.EndDateTime AT TIME ZONE maint.[TimeZone]);
```

If what you want is all checks and only those rows from maintenance that fall within the date range you can append an IS NULL to the where clause

```sql
Select check.appid, check.query, maint.appid 
from checks as check 
left join maintenance as maint on maint.appid = check.appid

WHERE
**maint.appid IS NULL OR**
SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()
            BETWEEN 
            CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET,maint.StartDateTime AT TIME ZONE maint.[TimeZone]) 
            AND 
            CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET,maint.EndDateTime AT TIME ZONE maint.[TimeZone]);
```

Comment: Ill try to be a bit more clear; 
I want all the checks where there is no maintenance and current time. 
So when an id with the start and enddate exist in maint i do not want to see it. 

When i use above queries i get same result as i got before. I either get all that ARE in maint. i need it the other way around.

Comment: So to be clear you want all checks that do not have any maintenance row and those that do have a maintence row but only where the maintence period does not include the current system date?